# Java Command Line when daemon is running

Tags: java

We all know what the code below does

```
class Demo{
     public static void main(String b[]){
         System.out.println("Argument one = "+b[0]);
         System.out.println("Argument two = "+b[1]);
    }
}
```

My question (infact curiosity) is, if this application is a daemon that is running and java based server waiting for clients to do socket stuff with it, can I run the application again, and pass new parameters to it ? Basically I am looking at **not** implementing a cli kinda thing. I need it simple.

Edit : I want to change / add more parameters at runtime. But if I run the app with new parameters, wont it start another instance ?

Comment: The question is slightly confusing. "can I run the application again, and pass new parameters to it"-Yes.. What do you want?: to change arguments on runtime or run another instance of application?

Comment: I think he/she wants to know if you can modify the arguments on the fly (so you don't have to write a CLI to pass them), in that case the answer is no.

Comment: Yes @Djon thanks. Thats what I thought. Please put in a answer.

Comment: @Siddharth I did, but you should really try to do a CLI, it's not that hard.

Comment: Sure, but why the downvote ? Its tough to keep track of everything happening in the programming world for something as vast as java. I was just wondering if there was a new way of doing things.

Comment: Stop crying, take my upvote :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't modify the arguments passed after the application started.

The array used to retreive the parameters is populated when it starts and cannot be altered.

If the application is a server, you should be able to implement a CLI rather easily with a simple thread waiting for input.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have an existing application that is being run as a command line application right now.  It is being invoked as and when required from command line passing the appropriate command line parameters.  And now what you would like to do is host this same application as a daemon service which gets invoked as and when the parameters come over a port it is listening to.

Assuming your goal is the above and for whatever reason you want to retain the above `main()` signature, the key is to realize that the `main()` method is also like any other static method which can be invoked by a class reference.  So the following is possible:

```
class SocketListener extends Thread {

    public void run() {

        // Code for listening to socket that calls invokeDemo() 
        // method below once it detects the appropriate args.
    }

    private void invokeDemo(String[] args) {

        // You can invoke the main method as any other static method.
        Demo.main(args);
    }
}
```

This would just treat Demo class as part of a library it is using and not launch any other application.  If you do want to launch it as an application (because of some special reason), you would need to use the Process and Runtime classes of java.